# Oracle database cannot be open due to maximum allowed database size exceeded

Tags: database, oracle

I cannot start (open) my Oracle 18c XE database due to maximum allowed database size exceeded error:

```
SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE OPEN;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12954: The request exceed the maximum allowed database size of 12GB.
```

and I cannot delete any data (truncate/drop table, drop user, ...) because the database is not open:

```
SQL> DROP USER LOCAL_DB CASCADE;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: Database not open
```

It looks like never-ending deadlock to me. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: There are some suggestions here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4318928

The discussion doesn't indicate if any of them worked.

Comment: Thanks for the link pmdba! Unfortunately there is no solution there so far. But maybe someone will post it. I'll keep checking that discussion.

Comment: Do you have a recent export?

Comment: Yes, I've got a dump of the schema.